# Set Theory Operations Union Only

Tags: code-golf, math

My obsession with set theory continues. I believe that most programming languages have neither sets as possible structures nor set theory operations such as Union and Intersection. If I am wrong then this question becomes trivial and I learn something new.

It would be fun to ask for the code golf construction of a full set structure where a set could contain any possible structures within the language and operators such as is a member of, is a subset of, union and intersection etc. However that is much too broad. So I will simplify the puzzle.

**Terminology**

An Alphaset has only lower case letters as elements.

The structure for an Alphaset can be defined as you wish and the method used should be explained. It could be just a list of letters read from a file.

As an example I will use an array as a structure for an Alphaset.

An Alphaset can contain a letter once only and order does not matter.

['a','b','c'], ['b','c','a'] and ['c','a','b'] are equivalent Alphasets.

The operation Union forms an Alphaset from two Alphasets.

['a','b','c'] Union ['d','a', 'g', 'b'] is ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'g'] or an equivalent.

A Big Alphaset has the same structure as an Alphaset but can contain repeated letters, eg ['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b'] is a Big Alphaset.

If A and B are any combination of Alphasets and Big Alphasets then A Union B must return an Alphaset.

This gives a way of producing an Alphaset from a Big Alphaset should it ever be necessary for when A is a Big Alphaset the A Union A will be an Alphaset.

**Puzzle**

**Input**

A an Alphaset or Big Alphaset

B an Alphaset or Big Alphaset

**Ouput**

An Alphaset that is the Union of A and B.

**Test Data**

Testing should demonstrate that order of elements within the Alphaset does not matter.

ie the following should all produce equivalent results.

['a','b','c'] Union ['a', 'c', 'd']

['b','c','a'] Union ['c', 'd', 'a']

['c','b','a'] Union ['d', 'a', 'c']

Shortest code wins

Comment: This is actually the built-in Ruby behavior for the `|` operator on arrays.

Comment: .NET also has sets built-in. (`HashSet<T>`)

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is extremely trivial.

Answer (score 3):

### Python2 - 21 (or 15) (or 1)

Sets should be in the format `set([element1, element2, element3...])`

```py
print input()|input()
```

If running from the interactive prompt is allowed, remove the `print`.

Note: If [the Mathematica answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/25754/12205) qualifies as being 1 character, then in the Python interactive prompt this should also qualify as 1 character:

```py
set(['a','b','d','z'])|set(['c','z','d','a','k','a'])
```

Sample input:

```py
set(['a','b','d','z'])
set(['c','z','d','a','k','a'])
```

Sample output:

```py
set(['a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'k', 'z'])
```

Comment: In Python 3, that would be `print(eval(input()+"|"+input()))`.

Comment: @golfer9338 You're right, I should probably specify Python2.

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica, 1 Chars

It's a built-in feature:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

## APL - 1 char

`∪` is the union operator, so `1 2 3∪3 4 5` returns `1 2 3 4 5`. In APL, there are no brackets around lists.

Other diadic (two-argument) set operators in APL are `∩` (intersection) and `~` (Without):

`1 2 3∩3 4 5` = `3`, `1 2 3 4 5~1 3` = `2 4 5`

Many languages have libraries built especially to deal with sets:

- Haskell - [Data.Set](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/containers-0.5.5.1/docs/Data-Set.html)
- Java - [java.util.Set](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) (an interface implemented by 8+ builtin classes)
- c++ - std::set
- Ecmascript 6 will have a [Set](http://people.mozilla.org/%7Ejorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-set-objects) object

Almost every language has some sort of way to handle sets. Usually googling "somelanguage set" will point you towards the documentation for that language's set

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 30

Not sure how strictly the input and output formats need to be followed, but this does a union correctly:

```
echo `tr \  "
"<<<$@|sort -u`
```

In action:

```
$ ./union.sh "a b c" "a c d"
a b c d
$ ./union.sh "b c a" "c d a"
a b c d
$ ./union.sh "c b a" "d a c"
a b c d
$
```

Answer (score 1):

## Golfscript, 3 bytes

```
~|p
```

#### Example

```
$ echo '["a" "c" "d" "b" "c"] ["f" "b" "e"]'| golfscript alpha.gs
["a" "c" "d" "b" "f" "e"]
```

#### How it works

```
~ # Interpret the input string.
| # Setwise OR (union)
p # print
```